# HttpClient authorization error on linux machine

Tags: c#, rest, web-services, postman, httpclient

This is my simple spike code:

```
var url = "http://url.de";
var username = "user";           
var password = "password";           

var client = new HttpClient();

var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", base64);

var result = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
```

On my Ubuntu server I always get a 401 authentication error with this code.
When I fire the webservice data on the same machine with Postman, the call works.

If I run the code directly on the webservice server (Windows Server) itself, the call works too.

What can be the problem?
Firewall is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
For whatever reason, the call via the code only works over HTTPS.